# Mixing single digit and double digit numbers - how to write formally

Tags: grammatical-number

If writing about numbers below 10, I spell the word out ('two out of four people use grammar correctly').

If writing about numbers greater than or equal to 10, I use digits ('15 out of 20 people use grammar correctly').

If I wanted to include the number five (5) and fifteen (15) in the same sentence, should I mix the type ('five out of 15 people use grammar correctly')?

Comment: [Read this](http://lcweb2.loc.gov/ammem/ndlpedit/handbook/numberdate.html)

Comment: Yes. Btw, numbers one to thirteen are usually spelled out as words, the higher ones being written in numeric.

Comment: Context matters here, also...if the main thrust of your writing is scientific and/or statistical, I would favor use of digits throughout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Chicago Manual of Style* (section 8.8, 13th ed.) says this about *Consistency*:

> Numbers applicable to the same category should be treated alike within the same context, whether paragraph or series of paragraphs; do not use figures for some and spell out others.

In your example, you are using numbers in a mathematical or scientific context. Section 8.11 says

> *Scientific usage.* In mathematical, statistical, technical, or scientific text, physical quantities, such as distance, lengths, areas, volumes, pressures, and so on, are expressed in figures, whether whole numbers or fractions.

You also must spell out the number if it is the first word of a sentence (section 8.9).

You might integrate all these rules like this:

- My informal study shows that only 5 out of 15 people use grammar correctly.